# Emgu webcam in VB beginner

Tags: vb.net, webcam, emgucv

lets go with the idea that i know nothing about nothing...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37l6-O0T6EA

I was following this vids, all going well. but failing on "capturez.QueryFrame"

```html
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure

Public Class Form1

    Dim capturez As Capture = New Capture

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Dim imagez As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.Retrieve() 'Instead of QueryFrame, you may need to do RetrieveBgrFrame depending on the version of EmguCV you download.

        PictureBox1.Image = imagez.ToBitmap()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `Retrieve()` method in vb.

Try to replace `capturez.Retrieve()` with `capturez.QueryFrame()` or `Capturez.RetrieveBgrFrame()`.

If you already changed that but you get failing on `capturez.QueryFrame`, it means you are missing some dll files in x86 (bin/debug).